C99's Non-Null Array Syntax Pointers for Parameters for MSVC
The following code:
int swap(int a[static 1], int b[static 1])
{
   ...
}

works with GCC, Clang, and ICX, but MSVC chokes on static in array parameters (or so I have been apprised by @Davilsor).
GNU C offers __attribute__((nonnull)) that is supported by Clang, GCC, and Intel's compiler. Is there a similar mechanism that MSVC offers?
I am looking to define a portable macro that would work under all 4 compilers.

MSVC is commonly lagging well behind the C standard, it's a third-class afterthought for their (really) C++ compiler.

Regarding __attribute__, MSVC uses __declspec instead. It should be well-documented (Microsoft usually have very good documentation).

Microsoft uses something called SAL (source-code annotation language) for annotating code, together with some analysis tools to check the code behavior matches the annotations.

MSVC supports C11 & C17 features but it doesn't support C99 at all although it does support most C99 features

What about using assert?  It's a macro and portable and can be used to ensure the parameters are not null.

@Jonathan I am mostly interested in learning Microsoft's way because this usage of static is critiqued quite a bit whenever I suggest it during code reviews because "MSVC does not support it". I wanted to suggest alternatives. assert() is extra code and would be disabled in release mode. And the static keyword doesn't require documenting that a nullptr is not a valid value for so and so arguments.

For a swap function, the notation int a[static 1] seems excessive to me, as does __attribute__((nonnull)).  I assume that you're really interested in more complex signatures.  I'm not sure how much you can rely on either the static or attribute notations ensuring that the pointers are not null at runtime, whereas an assertion can do that (at least for debug builds).  The notations tell the compiler it may assume the pointers are non-null, but the onus is still on the calling code not to pass null pointers.  Maybe there's some documentary benefit, though I am not convinced. YMMV!
